# The subject of the verb following while?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement, grammaticality-in-context

I remember I was taught in school that if the verb follows `while` its subject may not share the same suject with the main clause. For illustration, in the following [example](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html):

> While John was sleeping last night, someone stole his car.

I can paraphrase it into this form:

```
John's car(or the car of John) was stolen, while sleeping last night.
```

I don't know if it would be native but it's just an instantiation. The noun premodifier is the subject but for the following clause the subject is the noun adjunct of the subject in the main clause.

Am I right? I mean can the structure of the sentence be that robust? What is the related grammar?

Comment: *John dreamed while sleeping*, same subject after *while*. We don't *exactly* repeat a proper noun subject (so *John dreamed while John was sleeping* is "weird"), but we can freely use pronouns, so *John dreamed while he was sleeping* is syntactically and idiomatically fine. Your paraphrasing is *not* fine though - if unspecified, the subject must be that of the preceding clause (***John's car***, which obviously couldn't be "sleeping"! :)

Comment: *John's car was stolen while **he** was sleeping last night.* Without the pronoun, it sounds like it was the car that was sleeping. This is an example of a dangling participle. (And the comma may or may not be needed, depending on if John's sleeping is essential to what you're saying.)